# usage of __u32/__u16 types in userland code

Tags: c, types, long-integer, unsigned-integer

I observed that many userland code use types defined in 
`/usr/include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h`, such as `__u16`, `__u32` and alike. The comment in the header says:

> Integer declarations for architectures which use "long long" for
>   64-bit types

Would it be safe to apply macros from `stdint.h` defining maximum values for unsigned integer types, e.g. `UINT32_MAX`, to objects of type `__u32`?

Comment: You should use standard types where available, i.e. `stdint.h` types. These propriietary names are most likely legacies from before modern C (C99). Note that `__u32` is not necessarily the same type as `uint32_t`. Similar for the other types. Some compilers provide distingt built-in types and `stdint.h` `typedef`s just map to these internal names. gcc is such a compiler.

Comment: Many compilers, with all warnings enabled, will warn if the value is narrowed.  `__32 a = UINT32_MAX;`

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for comment. So it means that `/usr/include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h` is not Posix header either?

Comment: @Mark: I'd have to research on this myself, so please check yourself. But I doubt, because POSIX expicitly references the C standard and normally does not cover assembly stuff (that's the idea). Even if it was, you should always use the most common basis and the C standard **is** this basis. So always first use C standard features, then check for POSIX then compiler and/or platform specific features. On Winodws, things are different, of course (as always). Note that `__u32` etc well possibly are `tyedef`s/macros for the standard types, definitively not the other way 'round.